# CQRS - when aggregate roots in database and in a file?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have started planning for my first CQRS project with event sourcing and due to time constraints part of the model will remain in XML files. What I understand from DDD is that each update is done to an aggregate root and if I want to change another aggregate root from the first one (an event is raised in the domain) which first a command to modify the second aggregate. Each change has its own transactional boundary.

Now, what concerns me is if I have committed the change to the first aggregate (in a database) how do I handle the situation where the second aggregate (writing to a file in this case) fails?

I could issue a command to first update the file first (second aggregate) and then issue a command to change the first aggregate but once again I could have the second command fail but in this case here we have two separate commands which seem to go against the idea of events being raised in the domain that are handled as in the first case.

I suppose even if I wasn't using a file and all the changes were recorded in a database, there is a possibility that the second aggregate change could fail. Am I right to think this?

Still trying to get the concepts clear in my head so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second aggregate can emit something like an UpdateFailed Event. This in turn can be handled by sending a Rollback Command to the first aggregate.

Do you have a concrete example? Often the need for a transaction that crosses aggregate boundaries can be solved by refining the model.

**Update:** Also have a look at a concept called "Saga". A saga can be a helpful coordinator for cross-aggregate processes like yours. A saga is basically an event handler that submits commands according to the events it receives. A saga can be just a stateless coordinator, but it can also be stateful, so it knows which commands would have to to be compensated in case a subsequent one has failed. Just google "CQRS Saga" and go from there. Especially the articles by Greg Young and Rinat Abdullin are a very helpful read.

Comment: Thank you Dennis. I still think I am in the DDD lite camp and am trying to nail down my understanding. What I have is a licensing bounded context that uses JOliver's event store. With each license a type of service (Tv, video etc) is associated but these services are stored in an xml file. So creating a new license involves creating an xml record for it. My license aggregates seem to be separate from my service aggregrates and I cannot see how I could refine the model.

Comment: Supposing the model cannot be refined, the first aggregate fires a event which fires a command to the second. Is it correct to assume that? If now the second fails, I can send a "compensating command" (I think that is the terminology - please correct me) to the first aggregate. Is that correct?

Comment: @JD you're on the right track. In this case you would need some kind of compensating command. Also have a look at a concept called "Saga". A saga can be a helpful coordinator for cross-aggregate processes like yours. A saga is basically an event handler, that submits commands according to the events it receives. Just google "CQRS Saga" and go from there. Especially the articles by Greg Young and Rinat Abdullin.

Comment: Thanks. If you were in London, I'd buy you a meal. Cheers.

Comment: @JD I'll give you a call next time I'm in England. Glad I could help!

Comment: For those interested in sagas, found this excellent video : http://vimeo.com/20839681

Comment: Maybe I am being over cautious but what happens if the compensating command fails? Thinking non transactional is a bit of a stretch or am I missing some theory?

Comment: @JD keep the risk for this happening as low as possible. If it happens anyway, chances are that something went wrong. You can try to resubmit failed commands a few times. If they still fail, mail an admin who can have a look at what happened and decides on the required actions (e.g. manually injecting corrective commands through an admin console.)

Comment: Thanks. It is that coming from a world where things are done as one complete transaction (all or nothing) to where we have to think in terms of small transactions and compensation if things go wrong is a bit daunting. Thanks for all the help, I think over time things will get clearer :).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a question here more about transactional consistency then anything else.  Since you have given no real business context for the conversation, it is hard to comment fully about the appropriate solution.

However, in general, if the second aggregate **must** update based on the command to the first aggregate, then perhaps they are in the same transaction (DDD 'Bounded-Context'). It is really hard to know without the context.

Otherwise, usually, if the second aggregate has subscribed to the first's event, that message is received in a transaction (this time belonging to the second aggregate), and if that operation can not be fulfilled, the handling of the event is rolled-back and re-tried (or pushed to another place for manual action (like an error queue)).

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you that has helped a lot. Assuming they are in different "bounded-context", you said that if the operation on the second is not fulfilled, then the event is rolled back. I thought each change was in its own transaction? So first aggregate change is in its own transaction and the second aggregate change is in its own transaction.

Comment: A bit about the domain: First aggregate is in a licensing module and if a license can be applied to a server, then I create a service record in the XML file (which I have as my second aggregate).

Comment: So my second aggregate will be created as a result of the allocation of the license. Similarly when the license is revoked, I would delete the second aggregate (from the XML file).

Comment: @JD. What I meant was that the second aggregate's handling of the event would be rolled back and then tried again (either automatically or manually).  Because at this point the application is not behaving correctly (there is a bug).  I say this because the event that the first aggregate emits has been completely validated at that point.  The event has happened (past tense) whether the second aggregate takes action or not does not change the fact that the command was accepted and processed.